# How can I mark in the Circle use React or vanilla.js

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, npm

I want to use mark in the circle,onClick mark the dot,out put the json obj
Is there any npm package to use
[image]

onClick
[image]

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research - [search SO for answers](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+add+dot+coordinates+image+site%3Astackoverflow.com).  If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [\[<>\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just get click position relative to parent tag, and then move the child tag using style left/top.

```js
// get reference
let outer = document.getElementById("container");
let inner = document.getElementById("circle");

// add click listener to parent tag
outer.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    let result = {
    Azimut: {
        x: event.offsetX,
        y: event.offsetY,
    },
    Size: 10,
  }
  
  //
  inner.style.top = (result.Azimut.y - result.Size / 2) + "px"; //
  inner.style.left = (result.Azimut.x  - result.Size / 2) + "px";
  inner.style.width = result.Size + "px";
  inner.style.height = result.Size + "px";

})
```

```html
<div id="container" style="
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  position: relative;">
  <div id="circle" style="
    border: 1px solid black;
    position: absolute;
  "></div>
<div>
```